# Reducing Memory Access in a loop (C)

Tags: c

I have a question about reducing number of memory calls in a loop. Consider the following code (This is not my code as I cannot represent it here because it is too long):

```
for(k=0;k<n;k++)
{
    y[k] = x[0]*2 + z[1];
}
```

As you can see, in each iteration, the same blocks in the memory (x[0], z[1]) are being called . I was wondering if there is any way around to reduce memory access when the same block of memory is called several times.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: most of the times the compiler would take care of optimizations like this

Comment: If the same value is assigned to every element in the array. Why to calculate for every iteration. Calculate once and do a memset.

Comment: - and testing if your particular compiler does should be fairly trivial, just copy those two elements to locals and see if that makes it faster.

Comment: @Lefteris Not necessarily. If the compiler can't prove that `y` doesn't overlap with `x` or `z`, then it will be forced to redo the load every iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Simply, get the values before the loop:

```
i = x[0];
j = z[1];
for(k=0;k<n;k++)
{
    y[k] = i*2 + j;
}
```

Ofcourse the compiler will optimize this(*if it can*) even if you don't change anything but it helps to write more readable and intuitive code. You don't need to get the values on every iteration and the code you write should be indicative of that.
**Forget micro optimizations write more intuitive and readable code!**

As rightly pointed out in comments the right hand expression is completely independent of the loop, so:

```
i = x[0]*2 + z[1];
for(k=0;k<n;k++)
{
    y[k] = i;
}
```

Comment: hmmm, shouldnt you hoist `i*2` and then `i2 + j`.  The right hand expression is constant to the loop.

Comment: @RichardSchneider & Mystical: Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do.

```
float value =  x[0]*2 + z[1];

for(k=0;k<n;k++)
{
  y[k] = value;
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
v = x[0]*2 + z[1];
for(k=0;k<n;++k) y[k] = v
```

Assuming that x[0] and z[1] are NOT mapped to y[0..n-1]

Answer (score 1):

If `z` has a type that shorter than `int` (e.g. `char`) you can try the following trick:

```
char value = x[0]*2 + z[1];
unsigned int value32 = value | (value << 8) | (value << 16) | (value << 24);

unsigned int k;

// Going by blocks of 4
for(k = 0; k < n - n%4; k+=4) {
    (unsigned int)z[k] = value32;
}

// Finishing loop
for(; k < n; k++) {
    z[k] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will optimize this,

But in case you use a broken compiler without optimizations: you can put them both in `register` integers and then work with them. like this:

```
x0 = x[0]*2;
z1 = z[1];
y0 = x0 + z1;
register int k;
for(k=0;k<n;k++)
{
   y[k] = y0;
}
```

This does not guarantee that x[0] and z[1] will be on a register, but atleast hints the compiler that they should be on a register.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, we can't be sure that the compiler can optimize this. 'y[k]' might alias to 'x[0]' and/or 'z[1]'.

Comment: @JimBuck there is no other code and this code isn't the OP's either.

Comment: @JimBuck I think I know what you're saying

Comment: We don't know where 'x', 'y', and 'z' come from. If they are parameters to a function containing the OP's code, then all bets are off, and the compiler cannot optimize.

Comment: @JimBuck changed my answer to reflect that.